# Pandas combination of unique indices in two series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two Pandas series:

```
d1 = pd.Series(index=['a','b','c','d'],data=[100,200,300,400])
d1.index.name='letter'
d1.name='value'

d2 = pd.Series(index=[1,2,3], data=[.75,.5,.25])
d2.index.name='number'
d2.name='pct'

print d1
print d2
letter
a    100
b    200
c    300
d    400
Name: value, dtype: int64
number
1    0.75
2    0.50
3    0.25
Name: pct, dtype: float64
```

I want to multiply each combination of rows from the two series. The resulting series will be a multiindex series for each of the 12 combinations of [a,b,c,d] and [1,2,3]. The values will be the product of each of these combinations.

I can achieve this by creating a dataframe with a multiindex and then joining each of the two series. What is the better way to do this?

```
d3 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d1.index, d2.index],names=['letter','number'])).join(d1).join(d2)
print d3.value*d3.pct
letter  number
a       1          75.0
        2          50.0
        3          25.0
b       1         150.0
        2         100.0
        3          50.0
c       1         225.0
        2         150.0
        3          75.0
d       1         300.0
        2         200.0
        3         100.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [103]: pd.Series(np.outer(d1, d2).ravel(),
     ...:           pd.MultiIndex.from_product((d1.index, d2.index)))
     ...:
Out[103]:
a  1     75.0
   2     50.0
   3     25.0
b  1    150.0
   2    100.0
   3     50.0
c  1    225.0
   2    150.0
   3     75.0
d  1    300.0
   2    200.0
   3    100.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use  `stack`

```
pd.DataFrame(data=d1.values[:,None]*d2.values,index=d1.index,columns=d2.index).stack()
Out[1347]: 
letter  number
a       1          75.0
        2          50.0
        3          25.0
b       1         150.0
        2         100.0
        3          50.0
c       1         225.0
        2         150.0
        3          75.0
d       1         300.0
        2         200.0
        3         100.0
dtype: float64
```